# IBM Datastage : Creating column that is calculation

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have a table which columns are location and credit, the location contains string rows which mainly is `location_name` and `npl_of_location_name`. the credit contains integer rows which mainly is `credit_of_location_name` and `credit_npl_of_location_name`. I need to make a column which calculates the ((odd rows of the credit  - the even rows of the credit)*0.1). How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify "odd rows" and "even rows" are you referring to row numbers? Because, unless your query sorts the data, you have not control over row order; the database server returns rows however they are physically stored.

Once you are sure that your rows are properly sorted, then you can use a technique such as Mod(@INROWNUM,2) = 1 to determine "odd" and zero is even.  This works best if the Transformer is executing in sequential mode; if it is executed in parallel mode then you need to use a partitioning algorithm that ensures that the odd and even rows for a particular location are in the same node.